# UIWebView's UIScrollView subview can scroll but bounce back to the frame without appearing vertical scroll indicator

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiimagepickercontroller

### Update - Solution 2nd

The first solution (below) works only in iOS 7, not in iOS 6 nor iOS 5. So another method is update the content size of scroll view when there occurs any scrolling movement using `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`, which works for iOS 7, 6 and 5.

Inside `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`, I record the highest content size height,

```
if (_currentWebPageContentHeight < [[_webView scrollView] contentSize].height) {
        _currentWebPageContentHeight = [[_webView scrollView] contentSize].height;
    }
```

And restore `_currentWebPageContentHeight` to default height (the height of web view) whenever the another web page is loaded or current page is reloaded.

### Update - Solution 1st

I find a work-around, though don't know why it works. Slightly change the `contentInset` of the scroll view would force refresh the `contentSize` to current one.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    /// Load image data in async manner from photo chosen in album or taken by camera
    // ....

    /// Refresh the contentSize of UIScrollView inside UIWebView
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [_galleryPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

        /// A patch to force refresh the contentSize of scrollView, 0.01 is chosen to give unnoticeable layout change to user
        [[webView scrollView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0.01, 0)]; // UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)
    } else {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            /// A patch to force refresh the contentSize of scrollView, 0.01 is chosen to give unnoticeable layout change to user
            [[webView scrollView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0.01, 0)]; // UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)
          }];
    }
}
```

### The Original Problem

Using Xcode 5, iOS 7, iPhone 5, no nib files, no manual added auto layout constraints.

In a project, there is a UIWebView where a button on the lower left corner, that button is used to upload photo from iPhone's photo album or camera to a testing web site.

When clicking on the `Choose` button when I tried to upload photo from album, the method `-(void)imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` gets called, when this method finishes, the UIImagePickerController disappear with animation, and a photo chosen is loaded. But UIWebView's UIScrollView subview, though can scroll down to the end of current web page,  but keep bouncing back to the visible frame of the UIWebView (origin.x = 0, origin.y = 64, size.width = 320, size.height = 568 - 64), also the vertical scroll indicator cannot be seen.

The frame/bounds of the UIScrollView embedded inside UIWebView is correct, I check it in the ^{} of the following statement:

```
// At the end of the -(void)imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
[imagePickerControllerInstance dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

I've also forced these values to be correct. But doesn't change the above unexpected behavior.

```
[[webView scrollView] setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
[[webView scrollView] setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[webView scrollView] setContentSize:(CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 64))];
```

About the numbers used above:

- 320 is the width in points of iPhone 5.
- 568 is the height in points of iPhone 5.
- 64 is the height in points of both status bar and navigation bar.

Anyone can solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `setContentSize:` to the actual CONTENT size, not the visible frame size. That is if your content is e.g. 1000px high, you should `setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, 1000)`. This way you tell a `UIScrollView` that it should scroll to show 1000px high content. If you set a `UIScrollView`'s content size equal to its frame, no scrolling is performed and no scroll indicators appear (only bouncing effect).

Comment: To @gWiz, Then how to get the actual content size?

Comment: For WebViews I use the following code: `CGFloat contentHeight= [[detailWebText stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight + document.body.offsetTop;"] floatValue];`

Comment: Hi @gWiz, what is the class of `detailWebText`?

Comment: Hi @gWiz, I call it this way: `CGFloat currentContentHeight= [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight + document.body.offsetTop;"] floatValue];` but it didn't give the correct content height.

Comment: Is your webView finished loading at that time? Could be that you need to also run this in `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`

Comment: No, @gWiz, `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:` is not called after dismissing the image picker controller.

Comment: I assume you have set your webView's delegate to `self`?

Comment: To @gWiz, No, webView's delegate is set as its controller, but the delegate of scrollView inside the webView is set as the webView. I broke the MVC model...

Comment: Hi @gWiz, Can you help explain why my solution (see updated stuff above) works?

Comment: It could be because you are forcing the WebView to refresh it's layout. Try using: `[webView layoutIfNeeded];` instead to force it re-layout and hopefully refresh content size.

Comment: To @gWiz, `[webView layoutIfNeeded];` doesn't work either. But I found out that my above method works only in iOS 7, not in iOS 6 nor iOS 5. So another method is update the content size of scroll view when there occurs any scrolling movement using `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`
(see update), which works for iOS 7, 6 and 5.